# How to setup CJK package?

Tags: texlive, cjk

Recently, I want to type Chinese chars in a LaTeX document. Hence, the package `CJK` is needed. However, in my TeX distribution, say `TeX Live 2012`, there was no `CJK` installed, so I tried to install it from the remote repository. But unfortunately, I failed.

[image]

[image]

What's the origin of this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You can now install TeX Live 2013.

Answer (score 3):

TeX Live is maintained by TUG, and its current version is `TeX Live 2013`. Since `TeX Live 2012` is no longer supported by the remote package repository, it could not get any new package or update from the remote repository. You should update your TeX Live to version `2013`, and then try to install the `CJK` package.

Comment: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) might be helpful.